# A complex domain name match rewrite rule

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I am trying to create a regex rule for the following,

The rule is for matching domain names with the following conditions

1. need to mach domain name , foo.com
2. need to match  a.com
3. need to match  domain name start with underscrore and followed by a charector number ( _f.a.com, _foo.foo.com , don't match _.com or _*.a.com)
4. need to match *.a.com or *.foo.com , don't match *foo.com or *_foo.com
5. don't end with dot

So far I reached the following regex

`^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|\*\.[a-zA-Z0-9])|[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9-]){0,254}[a-zA-Z0-9](?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,})+$`

The problem is it doesn't match *.a.com , it will match all other rule

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

- The pattern does not match `_f.a.com` because the `_` and the `f` can be matched here `[a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9-]`, but the following character is a dot that can not be matched by any of the alternatives and also not by the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` part right after the alternation
- The pattern does not match `*.a.com` for almost the same reason, only this time for `*.`

You can match all the examples using:

```
^(?:_|\*\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:_|\*\.)?` Optionally match either `_` or `.*`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the ranges
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` Optionally repeat the previous with a leading dot
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5zSben/1).

You can make the pattern more specific if you want, for example if there should be 2 or more characters after the last dot:

```
^(?:_|\*\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$
```

You can use the quantifier `{0,254}` for any of the character classes.

Comment: This doesn't match  foo-fun.com  or  foo_fun.com , _foo._as.com

Comment: @sherin Something like this will match all examples `^(?!_\.\w+$)(?:\*\.)?\w+(?:[.-]\w+)+$` https://regex101.com/r/8cpIGz/1